# Adding to package hook after it's been loaded

Tags: preamble, latex-base, hooks, lthooks

It was my understanding of kernel hooks that adding to a hook only affects instances that follow that addition. This seems true for in-document hooks. For example, with

```
\begin{quote}
some text
\end{quote}

\AddToHook{env/quote/before}{HOOK CODE}

\begin{quote}
some text
\end{quote}
```

the `HOOK CODE` only appears before the second `quote` environment.

In a package file, I was trying to figure out how best to produce an error if another package is loaded. To account for the incompatible package being loaded before, one can wait until `begindocument`, but I wanted to know if the error can come sooner (save a few milliseconds of other packages being loaded, etc.). I tried

```
\AddToHook{package/incompatpkg/before}{\PackageError{mypkg}{Error!}{}}
```

and it worked, even if `mypkg` was loaded after `incompatpkg`.

Simple tests show that if `\AddToHook` appears after `incompatpkg` is loaded, the "added" code is executed at the point of addition, not before `incompatpkg` (which would be impossible, based on how I understand TeX works; this is why we have aux files). If `incompatpkg` is not loaded, the code is not executed.

The following example shows my goal of erroring before `begindocument` is achieved by this; this errors after `tikz` is loaded but before `tcolorbox` is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AddToHook{package/amsmath/before}{\PackageError{mypkg}{Error!}{}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Is this expected, and if so, supported, behavior? To me it's rather unexpected; the current behavior of `\AddToHook{package/pkg/before}{CODE}` seems to me more like

```
\IfPackageLoadedTF{pkg}
  {CODE} % unexpected part: execute code immediately if pkg loaded
  {\AddToHook{package/pkg/before}{CODE}} % do expected thing if pkg not loaded yet
```

Comment: yes that is documented (in ltfilehook). The package hooks with a package name are special one-time hooks and also executed if the package is already loaded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I should really put all the hooks docs in one pdf file because I repeatedly forget about ltcmdhooks-doc and ltfilehook-doc. Please feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package/class hooks that include a name are One-Time hooks as Ulrike mentioned.

As packages and classes can only be loaded once so any later addition would silelty sit in the hook and do nothing, without a warning.

But the reason main for this is that a package may want to do something after another package has been loaded but it can't know if the package gets loaded not at all, later or has already been loaded. Executing it it immediately if already loaded solves that case without the need for a lot of tests.

Obviously, for "/before" this is less likely to help, but that depends a bit on the reason for using the hook.  So one may have to test if the package was already loaded in the hook and complain, but again no need for special handling if it is loaded later.